# how to take multiple outputs from a loop to outside in python(netmiko)

Tags: python, python-3.x, netmiko

I am a newbie to the python. I have code to run multiple 'show commands' on multiple switches using netmiko, which is working fine when everything is within the loop. But when I want to take this output of the multiple 'show commands' outside the loop by assigning it as a variable and print it, only prints one of the outputs.

```
S1 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.0.56',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin'
    }

S2= {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.0.57',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin'
    }

all_devices = [S1,S2]


for devices in all_devices:
    print("\nLogging into the switch...")
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
    net_connect.enable()
    cmd = ["show vlan brief", "\n","\n","show ip interface brief"]
    for show in cmd:
        output=net_connect.send_command(show)
        y = output

print(y)
```

Comment: Well ... you _overwrite_ `y` all the time. Use a list and append to it instead. Only the last content of `y` survives.  Place a `y = []` before `for devices in all_devices:` and replace `y = output` by `y.append(output)`

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
S1 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.0.56',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin'
    }

S2= {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '192.168.0.57',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'admin'
    }

all_devices = [S1,S2]

y = []

for devices in all_devices:
    print("\nLogging into the switch...")
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**devices)
    net_connect.enable()
    cmd = ["show vlan brief", "\n","\n","show ip interface brief"]
    for show in cmd:
        output=net_connect.send_command(show)
        y.append(output)

for x in y:
    print(x)
```

Comment: If you now fix `y.appned` to `y.append` you successfully implemented what I wrote in my comment to this question. Congrats.